# How do I edit from a view using a viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a large entity (organization), and I've broken out some of the fields into separate views with a smaller subset of fields with several ViewModels.  I'd also like to use these same views if a user needs to update these fields later.

I'm confused as to how I should populate the data.  For example, I (probably foolishly) thought that if I populated the Get with the whole entity then the fields would be populated automatically - as if I was using an edit view associated to the whole entity.

Can someone tell me if ViewModels shouldn't be used this way or if I'm just not thinking about something obvious?

Here's my current Get/Post based on my (likely poor) assumption.  CompanyInfo is a subset of fields from within Organization.  This gives me the frustrating "dynamic proxies" error.

```
// GET: /Organization/CompanyInfo
public ActionResult CompanyInfo(ManageMessageId? message)
{
    ViewBag.StatusMessage =
    message == ManageMessageId.ConfirmEmail ? "Please confirm your email address to log in again." : "";

    var member = GetUserMember();
    var org = db.Organizations.Single(x => x.OrgId == member.OrgId);

    return View(org);
}

//
// POST: /Organization/CompanyInfo
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> CompanyInfo(CompanyInfoViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var member = GetUserMember();
        var org = await db.Organizations.SingleAsync(x => x.OrgId == member.OrgId);
        org.StreetAddress = model.StreetAddress;
        org.Suite = model.Suite;
        org.City = model.City;
        org.State = model.State;
        org.Zip = model.Zip;
        org.Country = model.Country;
        db.Entry(org).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("CompanyInfo", "Organization");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Your CompanyInfo action should return CompanyInfoViewModel not the db entity itself.  You should use your organization data to create this VM and return it to view. Your Post action looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real problem with having one ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC is that when you post it back you don't know what properties have been populated by the View since, as you state, you're only populating a subset of them on the various views. The pattern you should ideally follow is that you have one ViewModel for each View (and as the first comment on this post said you should be passing that, not your model, to your View to begin with).

One thing that you'll certainly find problematic with your approach is using the built in annotated validations, as each View will have different validation requirements since they are dealing with different parts of your entity.

Also I want to mention that when we talk about ViewModel's in ASP.NET MVC we are not talking about the same thing as ViewModel's in a XAML based UI framework, or even JavaScript libraries like Knockout or Angular 2. Those ViewModel's can be shared between views and even applications because of the nature of them existing on the client: that is the business logic can be executed against the View at consumption-time.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `CompanyInfo(ManageMessageId? message)` action method returns `db.Organizations.Single(x => x.OrgId == member.OrgId)`, which I'd bet is of type `Organization` (or something), but definitely *not* of type `CompanyInfoViewModel`.

What you should be doing is building a `CompanyInfoViewModel` in your first method out of the `org` object data.

---

Using View Models are acceptable in this scenario, though generally they're referred to as DTO's in this case. (Data-Transfer Objects) I generally name them `____ViewModel` for any `View` actions, `____EditModel` for `Edit` actions, etc. They're not *just* `ViewModel` objects, they are for other operations too. (Sometimes we have *really* complex things to do that require their own DTO for it.)